# Hi! Can You tell me what this Word is (is it a brand?

Tags: translation

[image]

I  think this might be a brand name .
I have this little charm and I’m dying 
To find where iit comes from. Or how to buy more.
Thank you INCREDIBLY for your help.

Comment: Wrong forum. It's Japanese and upside down.

Comment: LOLOL THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Japanese and it says:

Guriko (Glico) グリコ

Kafeore (Café au lait) カフェオーレ

Glico is a food brand and Kafeore is one of its product lines: http://www.cafeore.jp/info/

Comment: Oh you translated it!!! IM SO HAPPY!!  And impressed!  I can’t thank you guys enough!